# How to use .every with callbacks inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Lets say we have a list of items I want to check. If one items is not valid, I want to exit the .every function. Looking up the definition you can exit .every when on of the elements returns false. But how can you implement such a behavior when the function which does the check is using callbacks?

```
resultList.every(function (item) {
  return doCheck(item)
});

doCheck(item){
  _checkDBforValidEntry(item, function (err) {
     if (err) {
       return false;
    }else{
       return true;
    }
 });
}
```

This is a simple (and maybe not complete) example but it demonstrates my problem. This doesn't seem to work the way I expected. Are the statements placed wrong? Is this a constellation which doesn't work at all? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Doesn't seem like `_checkDBforValidEntry` is synchronous. You're supplying a callback to it and the `return` statements are *inside* that callback. The `doCheck` function itself doesn't have any `return` in it, so it always produces `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ but how do you use the return statement from the callback as the return of the doCheck surrounding function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promisify `doCheck`, then use a `Promise.all` which throws as soon as one iteration has an error:

```
const doCheck = (item) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  _checkDBforValidEntry(item, function (err) {
     if (err) {
       reject();
    }else{
       resolve();
    }
 });
};
Promise.all(resultList.map(doCheck))
  .then(() => {
    // Everything successful
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // At least one failure
  });
```